# Nil zone for new Time

Tags: ruby

If a `Time` instance is created in the default timezone, `zone` is not `nil`:

```
irb> n=Time.now
2016-06-27 14:07:19 -0500
irb> n.zone
"CDT"
```

However, if a `Time` instance is created by specifying the offset, `zone` is `nil`:

```
irb> n=Time.now
2016-06-27 14:07:19 -0500
irb> et=Time.new(n.year,n.month,n.day,0,0,0,"-04:00")
2016-06-27 00:00:00 -0400
irb> et.zone
nil
```

Is there a way to get the `zone` in situations like this?

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not a way to do that, and for good reason: A UTC offset can (and usually does) correspond to many different time zones. The offset you mentioned, -04:00, is a good example: It corresponds to [about fifty different time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).